# Color Dropdown in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a dropdown menu to change the color of my player in unity but it wont work. Here is my code:

```
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class colorSelect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Dropdown ColorDropdown;
    public static float speed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    public void ChooseColor()
    {
        switch (ColorDropdown.value)
        {
            case 1:
                GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.cyan;
                break;
            case 2:
                GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.red;
                break;
            case 3:
                GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.white;
                break;
            default: // speed if no item is selected. in this case, the player does not move
                speed = 0.0f;
                break;
        }

    }
}`
```

I tried using a switch statement and then attactched the script to the player and then the player to the dropown menu but it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to access the value of a dropdown is through the OnValueChanged event.

This may be of use:

https://docs.unity3d.com/2023.1/Documentation/Manual/script-Dropdown.html

Also the script should be attached directly to the dropdown.